# How to prove $\mathcal{L}e^{-U}g = e^{-U}\mathcal{L}^*g$ for Fokker-Planck operators

Tags: functional-analysis, mathematical-physics

Let $U$ be sufficiently smooth, $\beta$ a constant and 
$$
\mathcal{L}p   = \frac{1}{\beta}\Delta p + \nabla\cdot(p\nabla U)\\
\mathcal{L}^*g = \frac{1}{\beta}\Delta g - \nabla g \cdot\nabla U.
$$
Now I want to show that $\mathcal{L}e^{-U}g = e^{-U}\mathcal{L}^*g$.

Using the Laplacian product rule everything just started to look even worse, i.e.:

$$\mathcal{L}e^{-U}g = \frac{1}{\beta}(e^{-U}\Delta g + 2\nabla e^{-U}\nabla g + \Delta e^{-U} g) + \nabla e^{-U}g\nabla U + e^{-U}\nabla g\nabla U + e^{-U} g \Delta U$$

The $\frac{1}{\beta}e^{-U}\Delta g$ terms would cancel out just fine, but I don't see how to get rid of the other terms with a $\frac{1}{\beta}$.

Factoring out the $e^{-U}$ does not even work in the one dimensional case ($\nabla = \frac{d}{dx}$); there I get:

$$e^{-U}\left(\frac{1}{\beta}(g''-2Ug'+U'^2-U'')-gUU'+g'U'+gU''\right)$$

which doesn't really resemble

$$e^{-U}\left(\frac{1}{\beta}g''-g'U'\right).$$

(I would like to comprehend equation (2.16) in [this paper](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~nadler/Publications/diffusion_map_MMS.pdf))

Comment: Yes, we are. That's just what I tried, but I'm stuck with said term (added it in the question) and I don't see a way to rescue this ansatz, so I wanted to ask if there'd be a more sophisticated approach.

Comment: Ahh, that explains quite a lot, now (at least in 1D, but that's enough to convince me for now) it reduces to $e^{-\beta U}\mathcal{L}^* g$! Do you want to post this as an answer so I can mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there might be a missing $\beta$ in the exponent $e^{-U}$ meaning it could be that the relation that they mean is
$$
\mathcal{L}e^{-\beta U}g=e^{-\beta U}\mathcal{L^*}g.
$$
At least it seems that their relation holds if one replace $\beta$ by $1$.